# Pycharm stuck on "Installing Package", how to get log info?

Tags: pip, pycharm, pipenv

I'm running PyCharm Professional 2019.1.3 on a Windows 10 1803 box.  Python 3.7.3 with PIP 19.1.1

All of a sudden I'm not able to install packages using PipEnv in Pycharm. It get's stuck on "Installing Package...."  No matter what the package.  I've tried new projects, in different folders, disabled CrashPlan (I can't disable the AntiVirus (TrendMicro))

I have no issues installing packages from the CLI.

I've looked in the `C:\Users\<me>\.PyCharm2019.1\system\log` folder and the idea.log file doesn't mention anything about installing packages.

Is there another log file? Or a way do increase debugging or see what's going on?

Comment: What kind `File - Settings - Project Interpreter` has? Pipenv?

Comment: @dangel Were you able to find out if pycharm has such a log?

Comment: no luck, I don't recall what the fix was either, but I know the issue didn't stick around for long.  Is your issue with pipenv as well?